# What causes the "Error code: 1871" in my XML sitemap?

Tags: xml, sitemap

My question is what is this error code: 1871 and how this error effects on my XML sitemap search engine indexation by Google? Any negative effect?

Look at the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Could you please add some more details?